# Parameter changes for all deployments when upgrading the version

Tags: devops, kubernetes-helm

I have a problem with Helm templating.
I'm making a generic template for deployments and using:

```
{{- range $index, $service := .Values.services}}
```

to enumerate parameters from values.yaml file.
I want to interactively change the deployment version parameter when running:

```
helm upgrade ... --set appVersion=<my version>
```

But a problem arises that my deployment parameters are located inside services in values.yaml, and the appVersion parameter does not go there.

values.yaml:

```
services:
   firstservice:
     name: firstservice
     productCode: product-code
     imageRegistryHost: myregistry
   ...
   secondservice:
     name: secondservice
     productCode: product-code
     imageRegistryHost: myregistry
   ...
```

deployment.yml:

```
{{- range $index, $service := .Values.services}}
---
...
    spec:
       containers:
       - name: productcontainer
         image: {{ $service.imageRegistryHost }}/{{ $service.productCode }}/{{ $service.name }}:{{ $service.appVersion }}
...
{{- end }}
```

How can I set the appVersion parameter when upgrading a deployment?

Comment: `--set services.firstservice.appVersion=...`?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn’t work. I need to set the appVersion parameter in all services in values file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the setup you're describing, you need to include `appVersion` as a top-level parameter in your Helm values.

```
{{ $appVersion := .Values.appVersion }}
```

```bash
helm install --set-string appVersion=...
```

The `range` loop rebinds the special variable `.`, so you need to make sure you set the variable outside the loop.

```
{{ $appVersion := .Values.appVersion }}
{{- range $index, $service := .Values.services}}
image: .../{{ $service.name }}:{{ $appVersion }}
{{- end }}
```

If you want to allow a per-service version, but have a global default, you can use `default`

```
...:{{ $service.appVersion | default $appVersion }}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.